# OpenGL heads up display

Tags: android, opengl-es

For an opengl(es) game, the 'camera' moves about the xyz axes in response to user input via `gllookat`. Works so far. However I need to implement a heads up display that is in a static position at the corner of the screen. Knowing the current location of the camera, I draw the HUD. When the camera moves, the HUD jostles for a frame or two before returning to its proper location. Is there some good way of drawing a HUD in opengl that is not affected by the camera?

Comment: openGL es 1 or 2? If 2, you could simply use a different shader for the HUD.

Comment: I'm using 1 but it wouldnt be a problem to upgrade if that would correct the issue.

Comment: There is probably an easier solution to your problem without having to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just reset the MVT matrix to use a fixed camera position before you draw the hud - and given that the camera and view for the hud is fixed you only need to calculate it once.  I've done this on gles2.0, but it should work in earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you start drawing a frame remember your last position (save it in a variable) and use this data. This should remove all problems.